# TextAreaFor with New Lines causes Inner Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This might be simple, but.....

I have a view that includes a text area: `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ContactInfo)`

Without any new lines or using `@Html.EditorFor`, everything works smoothly. When I type an address for example...

```
 John Doe
 1 Right Way
 New York, NY
```

...the following inner exception occurs:

`"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."`

How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: The exception message is not related to the TextArea, is a SQL server error.. How do you send the data to sql server?

Comment: I believe this is generally a SQL exception, for when the string length is too long for the data length. What size is your data column (if you are inserting into db)

Comment: @munissor Very well, How do I resolve it? Do I have to parse the new lines in `\n` notation for the database to accept it as a one-line string?

Comment: Usually this happens when the maximum length of a field is less than the length of the text you are trying to fit in... 
Without the code is difficult to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curt hit the nail on the head. I only had a `varchar(10)` in that field. Silly me.

Lesson learned: "See what a specific field can take before jumping to conclusions."